# Generate Application Files in the root of the project when publish

Tags: wpf, xbap

When i publish XBAP application i want to get the files created in root of the project only but it gets created within Application Files folder.

Current Publish structure :

Project : WpfBrowserApplication1

After publish it generate files in to below path :

> WpfBrowserApplication1\publish\Application
>   Files\WpfBrowserApplication1_1_0_0_12

which contain below files:

> WpfBrowserApplication1.exe.deploy
>
> WpfBrowserApplication1.exe.manifest
>
> WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap

I want to get these files generated in root only :
For eg:

> WpfBrowserApplication1\WpfBrowserApplication1.exe.deploy
>   WpfBrowserApplication1\WpfBrowserApplication1.exe.manifest
>   WpfBrowserApplication1\WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap

I tried moving the files by just copying but it throws the error when running xbap application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure the default structure of publish , but you can manage in other way ie moving the files in your target folder and modify the codebase path which resided in the file WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap

```
 <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\WpfBrowserApp_1_0_0_0\WpfBrowserApp.exe.manifest" size="6964">
```

So you have to just change the codebase path in to your target path and move all files inside a publish folder to your target one and it will work.